# Is there a way to combine a google sheets query with a join to filter by a list

Tags: google-sheets

I have created the following formula

'=QUERY('Looker HVT'!A:AA,"select A,B,C,D where AA matches '" & join("' or A = '",Mapping!G:G) & "'",1)'

The formula runs okay and doesn't return any errors but it also doesn't return any results. The list in G:G matches the list in HVT AA:AA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is for instance

```
"select A,B,C,D where AA matches '"&textjoin("|",true,Mapping!G:G)&"' "
```